# How to exit from for loop if any itteration command failed in the loop

Tags: batch-file

I am deploying the **sql dacpac** on all databases one by one by putting them in text file and using for *loop*, I want to stop the deployment if any database failed to deploy successfully.

I created one batch script like below

```
"SQLCMD.EXE" -S DB -U user -P password -Q "SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases Where [name] NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')" -o alldb.txt

for /f "delims=" %%x in (alldb.txt) do (
    "SqlPackage.exe" /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"dacpac" /TargetDatabaseName:"%%x" /TargetServerName:"DB" /TargetUser:"user" /TargetPassword:"password"
    if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel% 
)
```

when I run this batch file, `if` command is executing along with `sqlpackage.exe` command like below

```
"SqlPackage.exe" /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"dacpac" /TargetDatabaseName:"DB name" /TargetServerName:"DB" /TargetUser:"user" /TargetPassword:"password"

 if 0 neq 0 exit /b 0
```

so deployment is going to start on next db even though previous db deployment got failed.

I need a way that if any db failed to deploy it should not start the deployment on next db and entire batch script should stop and give the errorlevel in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Below syntax worked for me.

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (alldb.txt) do (
   "SqlPackage.exe" /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"dacpac" /TargetDatabaseName:"%%x" /TargetServerName:"DB" /TargetUser:"user" /TargetPassword:"password" || echo ERROR && exit /b
)
```

Comment: probably you mean `... || (echo ERROR & exit /b)`?